# How do I make tab button clickable?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my navigation bar clickable. For example when a user clicks data a data web page opens up. But in my code I am unable to do so. When I click the tab button nothing happens. Can someone help me so that when I click the tab button shows the content? Note I am using bootstrap nav-nav tab bar Below is my code below:-

```
  <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">

      <title>Sales</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- Custom CSS -->
      <link href="css/shop-item.css" rel="stylesheet">


      <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">





  </head>

  <body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"> Main</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="persons/data.html"> data </a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="teams/teamI.html"> teams </a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="row">

              <div id= "mapContainer" class="col-md-12">
                  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
              </div>
              <div id = "panelContainer" class="col-md-3 hidden">
               <div  id="right-panel"></div>
             </div>
          </div>

      </div>

      <!-- /.container -->

      <div class="container">

          <hr>



      </div>
    </div>


      <!-- /.container -->

      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

      <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Did you initialise the tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler like below. But if you wanted to load another html into specific tabs then use `jquery`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"> Main</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#data"> data </a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#teams"> teams </a></li>
</ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     <div class="container">
       <h1>Home</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
     <div id="data" class="tab-pane fade in">
     <div class="container">
       <h1>Data</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="teams" class="tab-pane fade in">
     <div class="container">
       <h1>Teams</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> Update: You can also add html inside your tabs using jQuery load
>   function.

Code looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"> Main</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#data"> data </a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#teams"> teams </a></li>
</ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     <div class="container">
       <h1>Home</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
     <div id="data" class="tab-pane fade in">
     <div class="container">
       <h1>Data</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="teams" class="tab-pane fade in">
     <div class="container">
       <h1>Teams</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <script>
    $('#home').load('/home.html');
    $('#data').load('/data.html');
    $('#teams').load('/teams.html');
 </script>
```

Comment: hey mate thanks for that.. And i am trying to load different html pages into the various tabs. Not just content

Comment: okay i'm a little confused. How do i use the jquery? I'm not fond of jquery.

Comment: so it would be something like   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href=$('#date').load('/data.html')> data </a></li>

Comment: @ThomasC, no. you need to add the script inside a `<script>` tag.

Comment: so  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href=<script>$('#date').load('/data.html')</ > > data </a></li>

Comment: @ThomasC, check it now

Comment: oh my gosh i about to lose my mind. This still doesnt display the new web page in the tab.